# How to fix bad basic decoding?

Tags: java, encryption

When i use this simple encode/decode method i have a small error. When user input through scanner is like : 
String :   " Hello my name is Michael" 
Encode :   "Pmttw(u?(vium(q{(Uqkpimt" 
Decode :   "Hello m7 name is Michael"

its decoded like 'y' is now '7'

```
public static String basicEncode(String key) {
String result = "";
int lon = key.length();
char d;
for(int i = 0; i < lon; i++) {
    d = key.charAt(i);
    d += 10;
    result += d;
}

return result;
}

public static String basicDecode(String key) {
    String result = "";
    int lon = key.length();
    char d;
    for(int i = 0; i < lon; i++) {
        d = key.charAt(i);
        d -= 10;
        result += d;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Solution: on default in my workspace (Eclipse/ Windows/ Preferences/ Workspace / Text file encodint  >>>> switch Default (Cp1250) to UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

Your code is missing a 10 in basicDecode. Apart from this a do not see your problem.

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String in = "Hello my name is Michael";
    String encoded = basicEncode(in);
    String decoded = basicDecode(encoded);

    System.out.println(in);
    System.out.println(encoded);
    System.out.println(decoded);
  }

  public static String basicEncode(String key) {
    String result = "";
    int lon = key.length();
    char d;
    for (int i = 0; i < lon; i++) {
      d = key.charAt(i);
      d += 10;
      result += d;
    }

    return result;
  }

  public static String basicDecode(String key) {
    String result = "";
    int lon = key.length();
    char d;
    for (int i = 0; i < lon; i++) {
      d = key.charAt(i);
      d -= 10;
      result += d;
    }

    return result;
  }
```

This produces the following result:

```
Hello my name is Michael
Rovvy*w?*xkwo*s}*Wsmrkov
Hello my name is Michael
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to get this:

Encode : "Pmttw(u?(vium(q{(Uqkpimt"

for your code then

```
public static String basicEncode(String key) {
String result = "";
int lon = key.length();
char d;
for (int i = 0; i < lon; i++) {
  d = key.charAt(i);
  d += 8; //CHANGED TO 8
  result += d;
}

return result;
```

}

That is by entering "Hello my name is Michael"  as the String for the basicEncode method.

Can you tell me what the goal of this program is? What method is appropriate for the initial String to be placed in?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is something with UTF-8 on my computer, because when i was executing these same code on another pc environment it worked fine.

How can i check what is wrong ?

I know that when i want to change number of position to less than 8 it works good, but why not  if it 10 or greater ?

Comment: Change UTF-8 to Cp1250 worked for me.

Windows -> Preferences -> Workspace -> "Text file encoding" set to Default (Cp1250)